# Need Help with Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im currently creating a zend form status dropdown to let users to update their status.

All the status values are coming from the the database. 
Using the getProviderQuoteStatus($providerId,$quoteId,$quoteStatusId) method to determine what status is available to the user.

The problem I'm facing at the moment is when the form go through the validation process.

I'm keep getting `'1' was not found in the haystack` (because the status values is populated in the controller and not in the form itself therefore the providerQuoteStatus form element array is empty) . Can anyone help me out how can I solve this problem?

Thanks so much in advance!

```
  private function getProviderQuoteStatusForm()
    {

             $form = new Application_Form_ProviderQuoteStatus(array(
             'action' => '/leads/update-Provider-Quote-Status'
             ,'method' => 'post',
             ));

             return $form;
    }

private function getProviderQuoteStatus($providerId,$quoteId,$quoteStatusId)
    {

             $form = $this->getProviderQuoteStatusForm();

            $providerQuoteStatus = new Application_Model_DbTable_ProviderQuoteStatus();
            $providerQuoteStatusValues = $providerQuoteStatus->                   
                                         getProviderQuoteStatusUpdateValues ($quoteStatusId);   

           $form->getElement('providerQuoteStatus')->addMultiOptions($providerQuoteStatusValues);
           $form->getElement('providerQuoteStatus')->setValue($quoteStatusId);
           $form->getElement('quoteId')->setValue($quoteId); // set Quote Id to the hidden field
         return $form;
    }





    public function updateProviderQuoteStatusAction()
    {

                $form = $this->getProviderQuoteStatusForm(); // Status Update dropdown box
                $this->view->form = $form;

           if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
            { // is post type request has been made
                $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();


                if ($form->isValid($formData))
                        { // form elements has been validated

                                  $quoteId = $form->getValue('quoteId');
                                  $providerQuoteStatus = $form->getValue('providerQuoteStatus');
                                     $this->_helper->redirector('lead'); // redirect back
                                 // $this->_forward('leads');
                        }
                           $form->populate($formData);

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the [Zend Website](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html):

*By default, this element registers an InArray  validator which validates against the array keys of registered options. You can disable this behavior by either calling setRegisterInArrayValidator(false), or by passing a FALSE value to the registerInArrayValidator  configuration key.*

I have had this problem before and disabling this default validator does the trick.

Comment: Thanks so much! Work perfectly now :)